# Training time finished without any models trained

Tags: machine-learning, blazor, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I am trying to follow basic ML.NET tutorials on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83kEkJEXQnY&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oUDTvk5XMNues09FnuB_D0u&index=2&ab_channel=dotnet).

I have a Blazor app and added support for ML.NET using `Add->Machine Learning Model...`  menu from solution explorer.

I have selected the scenario as `Data Classification` and input data in the CSV format.

My CSV data looks like

```
id,name,review
1,Hemant,Product was gery good.
2,Arushi,Very bad quality.
3,Aaroh,Its average quality.
```

I have selected a column to predict as `review`

Time to train is default i.e. 10.  After I click `Train` I am getting below error message after 10 seconds.

`Model Builder Error`

`------------------------------`

`at Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLService.Experiments.LocalAutoMLExperiment.<ExecuteAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in /_/src/Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLService/Experiments/LocalAutoMLExperiment.cs:line 202 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLEngine.<StartTrainingAsync>d__21.MoveNext() in /_/src/Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLService/AutoMLEngineService/AutoMLEngine.cs:line 160`

[image]

Am I missing anything?

I am using .net core 6.0 on windows 11.